# Problem with logout user. Express server api with JWT auth

Tags: express, logout

I'm trying to create a full-stack mern app. I use jwt authentication. I will save the token in local storage and the token will be removed from there with react.

I have tried with req.logout(), req.logOut() and req.session.destroy() and it doesn't work.
Thank you!

```
const signIn = (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  User.findOne({ email: email })
  .then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      const error = new Error('A user with this email could not be found');
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }

    if(!user.authenticate(password)) {
      const error = new Error('A user with this email could not be found');
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ 
        email: user.email,
        userId: user._id.toString()
      }
      , 'somesupersecret'
      , { expiresIn: '1h' });

      res.status(200).json(
        { 
          message: 'User successfully logged in!', 
          token,
          userId: user._id.toString()
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (!error.statusCode) {
          error.statusCode = 500;
          next(error);
      }

    })
}

const logOut = async(req, res) => {
  try{
    await req.logOut();
    res.status(200).json(
    { 
      message: 'User successfully logged out!',        
    });
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  signUp,
  signIn,
  logOut
}
```

I become errors like TypeError: req.logOut is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be done on the server. Just remove/invalidate your jwt token that is being sent by the client. Generally the token is stored in localStorage and/or cookies. Just delete that token and refresh the page, user will logout.

Comment: Thanks but is it reliably?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. In my experience this has been very safe.

Comment: Ok but is it ok to refresh single page app?

Comment: In logout cases, yes. If you look closely you can see that facebook does so too. Depends on you case. You can just delete the token and navigate to another page programatically with react router and handle the state/props as you like.